# Android Mediamuxer moov atom

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I am recording device screen using `Mediacodec` and `Mediamuxer` api everything is fine.

Now I want to stream this file while recording, but cant until `muxer` is stopped and moov atom is written at the end of file.

So my question is it even possible using `Mediamuxer` for the purpose? If not what are the alternatives?

[image: This is what I want to do, if not possible how cyanogen is doing?]

Comment: Just a question.. Is there a restriction for your use-case that you can't write to a file as well as stream simultaneously? If not, you could just create 2 sinks i.e. `MediaMuxer` and a streaming component and use same encoder output for writing as well as streaming

Comment: @Ganesh I didnt get you completely but my use case is I have to stream the recording to chromecast(while recording i.e. mirroring screen) and chromecast can't find the moov box so unable to play the file, BTW can you explain 2 sinks?

Comment: My point was more related to a NVR or DVR kind of use-case where a stream is simultaneously written to disk and streamed over net using `RTP`. Clearly this is not same as your use-case as you require a `DLNA` type transfer and as the answer below indicates, this is not possible..

Comment: I dont know if its possible but cyanogenmod have inbuilt app that does the same check updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

In order to send an MP4 file while it is being written, you need to write fragmented MP4, and MediaMuxer only writes non-fragmented MP4.

Comment: Ok is it possible to write moov atom at beginning rather at end with some fake data

Comment: No. In a non-fragmented MP4, the moov atom contains descriptions of every single packet in the file, which you cannot write until you've actually finished the stream.

Comment: This is what I want to do, if not possible how cyanogen is doing? check the updated question

Comment: The updated question contains an image that doesn't load. CyanogenMod probably is using some other API. You can do this yourself by using a different library to write MP4 instead of the built-in MediaMuxer. But how to do that is a different question than this. Please open new questions if you want to ask something else than what this question originally was.

Comment: The cast functionality does not use MediaMuxer, but uses other private APIs.

Comment: Check this https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/secure/attachment/44017/logcat.txt   same log in my phone It uses RTMP and they are using mediacodec api, although google states RTMP is not supported on Chromecast but logs shows otherwise

Comment: I don't see anything about RTMP in that log. And this is all _still_ unrelated to the question. The public `MediaMuxer` API does not support this.

Comment: Although I havent solved the problem but your answer is correct that it is not possible, I still figuring out how cynogen app does it I have created another question and marked it as solved Thanks

Comment: What about using `MediaMuxer` with WebM container?

Comment: @DimaRostopira you are asking or suggesting?

Comment: @bhardwaj asking

Comment: @DimaRostopira i though you already tried this ..hoping you suggestion

Comment: @bhardwaj I've tried killing app process while recording, and resulting webm file were playable just fine, I guess it worth trying for this case, but my case were completely different from question, so it didn't really fitted my needs